# Vuejs- run @click when using v-html to return html string?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, onclick, render

I have this html string:

```
errorText: '<a class="button" @click.prevent="enableExceedable(issue.mapping)">Enable exceedable limits</a>';
```

I want to add it inside this div:

```
<div v-if="hasIssue !== {} && issue.is_issue" v-for="(issue, key) in hasIssue" :key="key" class="issues" v-html="errorText"></div>
```

when I use v-html to return it, I see the button but @click doesn't run. I need a solution for that please.

Comment: String is not enough, provide your code also.

Comment: I edited it now, thank you.

Comment: Ok, I answered your question. Let me know if it is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

You are using v-html in wrong way. You should add

```
<a class="button" @click.prevent="enableExceedable(issue.mapping)">Enable exceedable limits</a>
```

inside your div

```
<div v-if="hasIssue !== {} && issue.is_issue" v-for="(issue, key) in hasIssue" :key="key" class="issues">
  <a class="button" @click.prevent="enableExceedable(issue.mapping)">Enable exceedable limits</a>
</div>
```

Comment: the problem is the string will not be the same always.
there is a function that gives the string, because of that I want to use v-html.
thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
<div
  v-if="hasIssue !== {} && issue.is_issue"
  v-for="(issue, key) in hasIssue"
  :key="key"
  class="issues"
  v-html="errorText"
  @click="processIssue(issue)"
>
</div>

data: {
  hasIssue: [],
  errorText: `
    <button class="button">
      Enable exceedable limits
    </button>
  `
},

methods: {
  processIssue (issue) {
    this.enableExceedable(issue.mapping)
  },
  enableExceedable (mapping) {
    // implementation
  }
}
```

PS: I'm using button instead of anchor. Use anchors only when they will really act as anchors, not just buttons. Better semantics. Recommended way.

Comment: the problem is the string will not be the same always.
there is a function that gives the string, because of that I want to use v-html.
thanks for your answer

Comment: Understand. And just text will differ? Or callback method too? Will be there different callbacks for different texts?

Comment: callback method also will change.

Comment: Edited. Is it now what are you looking for?